# Woocommerce rest api - Operation Timed out

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

So I need to pull all the customers from one of my wordpress/woocommerce and insert them into a centralised database on a regular basis (daily at least). I can connect to the api without any issues, but there seems to be an arbitrary rate limit set.

When i run the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {

    $data = array(
        'per_page' => 30,
        'orderby' => 'registered_date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'page' => $i,
    );


    $woocommerce = new Client(
        'https://example.com',
        'ck_xxx',
        'cs_xxx',
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v2',
        ]
    );


    try { 
        $customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', $data); 
    }
    catch(HttpClientException $e) {
        $err = $e->getMessage(); 
    }


    foreach($customers as $customer){

        $SystemID = $customer->id;
        $CustomerEmail = $customer->email;
        $CustomerFirstName = $customer->first_name;
        $CustomerLastName = $customer->last_name;
        $CustomerRoleName = $customer->role;
        $UserName = $customer->username;
        $SourceSystemCreatedDate = $customer->date_created;
        $SourceSystemLastEdit = $customer->date_modified;
        $RoleUUID = SelectCustomerRole($CustomerRoleName)['CustomerRoleUUID'];
        $Active = 1;

        $CustomerUUID = InsertCustomer($SourceSystemUUID, $SystemID, $CustomerEmail, $CustomerFirstName, $CustomerLastName, $Active, $SourceSystemCreatedDate, $SourceSystemLastEdit, $UserName, $RoleUUID);
        print_r($CustomerUUID);


    }


}
```

Ive tried re-using the connection object by moving it out of the loop, but that seems to fail even quicker.

I cant seem to find any documentation on how or why this is happening.

Is there a limit? 
Is there a way I can remove it? (I manage the hosting environment that i'm connecting to, so i can change anything on the server to make it work) 
Am I meant to be doing this a different way, id prefer not to be connecting directly to the database to get the information, but if I have to I will.

This is the output:

```
admin@ip-172-31-8-60:/var/www/esb$ php insertcustomer.php 
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119120121122123124125126127128129130131132133134135136137138139140141142143144145146147148149150151152153154155156157158159160161162163164165166167168169170171172173174175176177178179180181182183184185186187188189190191192193194195196197198199200201202203204205206207208209210211212213214215216217218219220221222223224225226227228229230231232233234235236237238239240241242243244245246247248249250251252253254255256257258259260261262263264265266267268269270271272273274275276277278279280281282283284285286287288289290291292293294295296297298299300301302303304305306307308309310311312313314315316317318319320321322323324325326327328329330331332333334335336337338339340341342343344345346347348349350351352353354355356357358359360361362363364365366367368369370371372373374375376377378379380381382383384385386387388389390391392393394395396397398399400401402403404405406407408409410411412413414415416417418419420421422423424425426427428429430431432433434435436437438439440441442443444445446447448449450451452453454455456457458459460461462463464465466467468469470471472473474475476477478479480481482483484485486487488489490491492493494495496497498499500501502503504505506507508509510511512513514515516517518519520521522523524525526527528529530531532533534535536537538539540541542543544545546547548549550551552553554555556557558559560561562563564565566567568569570571572573574575576577578579580581582583584585586587588589590591592593594595596597598599600601602603604605606607608609610611612613614615616617618619620621622623624625626627628629630631632633634635636637638639640641642643644645646647648649650651652653654655656657658659660661662663664665666667668669670671672673674675676677678679680681682683684685686687688689690691692693694695696697698699700701702703704705706707708709710711712713714715716717718719720721722723724725726727728729730731732733734735736737738739740741742743744745746747748749750751752753754755756757758759760761762763764765766767768769770771772773774775776777778779780781782783784785786787788789790791792793794795796797798799800801802803804805806807808809810811812813814815816817818819820821822823824825826827828829830831832833834835836837838839840841842843844845846847848849850851852853854855856857858859860861862863864865866867868869870871872873874875876877878879880881882883884885886887888889890891892893894895896897898899900901902903904905906907908909910911912913914915916917918919920921922923924925926927928929930931932933934935936937938939940941942943944945946947948949950951952953954955956957958959960961962963964965966967968969970971972973974975976977978979980981982983984985986987988989990991992993994995996997998999100010011002100310041005100610071008100910101011101210131014101510161017101810191020102110221023102410251026102710281029103010311032103310341035103610371038103910401041104210431044104510461047104810491050105110521053105410551056105710581059106010611062106310641065106610671068106910701071107210731074107510761077107810791080108110821083108410851086108710881089109010911092109310941095109610971098109911001101110211031104110511061107110811091110111111121113111411151116111711181119112011211122112311241125112611271128112911301131113211331134113511361137113811391140114111421143114411451146114711481149115011511152115311541155115611571158115911601161116211631164116511661167116811691170117111721173117411751176117711781179118011811182118311841185118611871188118911901191119211931194119511961197119811991200120112021203120412051206120712081209121012111212121312141215121612171218121912201221122212231224122512261227122812291230123112321233123412351236123712381239124012411242124312441245124612471248124912501251125212531254125512561257125812591260126112621263126412651266126712681269127012711272127312741275127612771278127912801281128212831284128512861287128812891290129112921293129412951296129712981299130013011302130313041305130613071308130913101311131213131314131513161317131813191320PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: cURL Error: Operation timed out after 15001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received in /var/www/esb/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:409
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/esb/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(82): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('customers', 'GET', Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/esb/insertcustomer.php(37): Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->get('customers', Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/esb/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 409
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `timeout` option to the Client options:

```
 $woocommerce = new Client(
    'https://example.com',
    'ck_xxx',
    'cs_xxx',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
        'timeout' => 400 // curl timeout
    ]
```

This sets the time internally for [CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html) as well as [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html)